# React with Gutenberg WordPress Editor - Impossible to implement a react-router with blocks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

According to the [serialization and parsing architecture documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/explanations/architecture/data-flow/#serialization-and-parsing) of the Block Editor Hanbook. Can I assume that every blocks are isolated from each other? There is no mean to directly make a communication between them through some reacts components or context?

I was facing this issue trying to implement a BrowserRouter component from the react-router-dom library. But it seems that the InnerBlocks have no idea of parent's blocks javascript.

**Edit :**

- Web Server : nginx
- PHP version : 8.0.0
- WordPress Version : 6.0
- Context : Plugin developpement for adding blocks to the visual editor.
- Issue : `Uncaught Error: useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.` when I try to add a `react-router-single-route` block inside a `react-router-wrapper` block through `InnerBlocks`.
- Goal : I want to implement a react-router in the WordPress gutenberg block editor. I want make a Routes component, as a block, be able to render an InnerBlock as the end user can switch from either one Route to another as one InnerBlocks as an other.
- [What are blocks ?](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/explanations/architecture/key-concepts/#blocks)  from https://developer.wordpress.org/
- Note : The plugin is bootstrapped by [@wordpress/create-block](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/create-block)

`package.json` dependencies and build for plugins/my-plugin in Wordpress :

```json
    "scripts": {
        "build": "wp-scripts build",
        },
    "devDependencies": {
            "@wordpress/scripts": "^23.2.0"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
        }
```

The parent block `react-router-wrapper-block/edit.js` :

```js
  /**
 * The edit function describes the structure of your block in the context of the
 * editor. This represents what the editor will render when the block is used.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-edit-save/#edit
 *
 * @return {WPElement} Element to render.
 */
  export default function Edit() {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps();
    return (
        <div {...blockProps}>
            <MemoryRouter>
                <h3>Wrapper</h3>
                <div width="100%" height="50%" {...blockProps}>
                    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                    <Link to="/test">Test</Link>
                </div>
                <InnerBlocks />
                <hr />
                <p>FIN du Wrapper block</p>
            </MemoryRouter>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Then the child block who will lives in InnerBlocks `react-router-wrapper-block/edit.js` in the visual editor.
`react-router-single-route/edit.js` :

```js
  /**
 * The edit function describes the structure of your block in the context of the
 * editor. This represents what the editor will render when the block is used.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-edit-save/#edit
 *
 * @return {WPElement} Element to render.
 */
export default function Edit() {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps();

    return (
        <div {...blockProps}>
            <h3>Single Route </h3>
            <Routes>
                <Route
                    path="/"
                    element={
                        <div {...blockProps}>
                            <InnerBlocks />
                        </div>
                    }
                />
            </Routes>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking about, or for, but I don't think `react-router` has anything to do with WordPress. `react-router` handles app-side routing/navigation. What is the issue?

Comment: I use @wordpress/scripts package to building gutenberg 'edit side' blocks in react. The issue is I want to use a MemoryRouter as a parent block for Routes and Links blocks. But the children, when declared in InnerBlocks, throws an error saying that there is no Router ancestor. So my question is : Why exactly my children blocks have no idea of the react/javascript context of their parents? Is this caused by the gurenberg serialization and parding lifecycle or I missing something?

Comment: What are "blocks" in this context. This isn't something `react-router`, i.e. routers, routes, links, etc... have anything to do with. From what I gather, your question is something specific to wordpress and "blocks" and using these within a specific React component you are rendering. I think it's *this* component that is interacting with wordpress/"blocks" that you need to clarify and provide a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for. We can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see.